# Compartir carpeta VMware Horizon Client

Tags: windows, virtualización, vmware

He buscado cómo crear una carpeta compartida entre un sistema destino, una VDI Windows 10 y un sistema origen, una máquina virtual con Windows 7; los cuales se comunican mediante VMware Horizon Client.

Necesito conocer si existe una forma de crear una carpeta compartida entre ambos

He consultado la siguiente documentación:

- https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/index.html
- https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-Client-for-Linux/4.0/horizon-client-linux-document/GUID-CFB7E9B1-63E0-418A-8814-572296507783.html
- https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-7/7.11/horizon-remote-desktop-features/GUID-25820640-60C2-4B7D-AE3F-F023E32B3DAE.html
- https://docs.vmware.com/es/VMware-Horizon-Client-for-Mac/4.6/com.vmware.horizon.mac-client-46-install/GUID-CFB7E9B1-63E0-418A-8814-572296507783.html
- https://docs.vmware.com/es/VMware-Horizon-7/7.2/com.vmware.horizon.remote.features.doc/GUID-25820640-60C2-4B7D-AE3F-F023E32B3DAE.html

Y el siguiente tema:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948267/sync-folder-of-vmware-host-and-guest

¿Podrían indicarme cómo se podría realizar?

Gracias

Un saludo

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: tu problema esta relacionada al manejo de aplicaciones en el sistema operativo, y no a algo relacionado a los objetivos del sitio (Desarrollo y programación).